# Did Installing OneCare cause a "Generating user instances in SQL Server is disabled" error?

Tags: sql-server

Did Installing OneCare cause a "Generating user instances in SQL Server is disabled" error?

The only change that I've made to my computer is uninstalling AVG and installing the trial for Microsoft OneCare. Did OneCare change the SQLServer installation somehow?

This is a very "odd" question but is something I would post on EE in hopes of someone having had the same issue and giving their solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would look more at the uninstalling of AVG as the culprit.  OneCare does not care or even notice SQL Server instances as far as I can tell where as AVG does.

I would look into your SQL Server instance and check the jobs.  One or more may have been added by AVG.  You should remove them.  You might also want to drop the AVG database.  Just to be sure.

Note: I have never **uninstalled** AVG.  I just have notice some of what it did to my Database when my SysAdmin installed it.  Being an Accidental DBA I haven't had the time to properly evaluate it's actions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your connection string.  When using SQLExpress you can set it to run user instances so that each application has its own instance of SQL Server.  Just set the option to false on your connections string and the problem should dissappear.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anything odd in the event viewer or any db's for avg in SQLServer. btw I installed SQL server after AVG. it's curious anyway. I'll just make a VM and do a fresh install of SQLExpress so I can finish a few projects.

it's been over a year so it's time for the annual reformat and reinstall ;-)

Answer (score 0):

@baldy

Thanks. I'll look at as well. Oddly enough though I didn't change the connection string at all. And when I created a new project and tried to drag-n-drop a DB into the LINQ to SQL diagram that error was raised then as well.